# Request for comment on coding style

Tags: java, coding-style

Comparing the two options below, I find the first option more readable, but the second is shorter and probably slightly faster. Out of these examples, is there any option that is generally accepted as better?

Option 1:

```
String query = "from User order by name";
ArrayList<User> result = (ArrayList<User>) session.createQuery(query).list();
return result;
```

Option 2:

```
return (ArrayList<User>) session.createQuery("from User order by name").list();
```

Comment: You should rather post this question in the "CodeReview" StackExchange http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: The second version is unlikely to be faster, so readability is the only difference.

Comment: Ah, thanks, didn't know about CodeReview!

Comment: Why do you think the second is "probably slightly faster"? The two options will probably compile to the exact same bytecode.

Comment: Right, so readability should take preference. Although, I'm not sure if others would agree the first is more readable.

Comment: Jesper: redundant variable (result).

Comment: My subjective opinion is that they are as readable but Option 2 will take less space on my screen and would be my preference.

Comment: In the second case you see the point of the whole code immediately: unconditionally returning a calculated value. This causes less cognitive burden (at least for me) than the first case, where I read the code in three separate breaths and am forced to make the connections between declaration and use in my head. But, this is definitely highly personal and related to specific details of one's cognitive processes. This is a "primarily opinion-based" question if there ever was one.

Comment: Also, as assylias mentioned, most implementation classes are large---and the more stuff you can fit on screen without the need to scroll around, the easier it will be for you to gain the overall insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Option 1` is more readable while `Option 2` does what you want to do is in single line.

Also `Option 1` use local variable `result` redundantly.

My opinion is following way is better.

```
String query = "from User order by name";
return (ArrayList<User>) session.createQuery(query).list();
```

It is readable and also no redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

generally accepted  ?

The first one. may be slightly faster, but you take 3 more sec for other to understand what's going on.

this artcle may be good for you

http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/276

Comment: There is no "general acceptance" here. It is highly personal.

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, would always approach code with 'readability' being a must. This is because if you need to edit the code at a later date, you can quickly grasp what is happening, and would take a lot less time to complete updates and/or patches.